# Javascript control page and user view page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently I'm working on a project where a user enters a lot of data constantly for a hour long window.  I'm looking to have one user control all the data via some control panel and then have a link they can distribute to other users that will allow them to view that data without the ability to edit it.

Right now I'm doing some extremely weird methods. I have an XHR request on the control page that fires whenever a field is finished being edited.  From there the data is sent to a php file that converts the data into a simple text file.  Then the distributed link file will load that file one time and translate it into the necessary format.

Some potential problems I've run into are it seems odd that I'm sending starting as javascript data then going to a php file then to a text file then translating the data all the way back into javascript data again.  Another problem I've come into is I'm not sure of a way to force users to reload the page when a field is edited in the control panel after the user has opened the view page.

Have I totally gone overboard here? What are some better concepts I could employ to accomplish this task?

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: imo everything you have done till now is good maybe except having configuration in text file (consider using database). JavaScript allows you to automatically refresh users page by some built in methods.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want to do this is how i will do this:

**First the data entry**

if you have lot of fields you better use a form wizard, i don't have a particular one in mind right now but there is lot of them just search jQuery Form wizard

Here is an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luk2b.jpg

The concept of the form wizard is to guide user via multiple page and also validate the data. And click save when and the end.
Then save date in database.

**Display content**

All you need to do is to create a global separate page to display your content.
Let see something like: http://yourserver.com/view/{id}
where id is the identifier of the particular row in your database.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i totally understand what u about to do. i'm trying to make your work description shorter here:

> want to build a website that one person can edit a single page's content in 1 hour, and others can view the content change in that 1 hour.

if this is what u want to build, here's the module:

**teacher**: the one who can edit the page

**student**: the one who can only view the page

**server**: information center

> teacher client edits page -> teacher client sends **update data** to server -> server saves data -> server sends **update notice** to student client -> student client receives **update notice** -> student fetches **update data** from server

to make this module work well, i suggest try **socket** instead of **http reqeust**, just like online games or IMs do.

well, try [socket.io](http://socket.io)